# LogNormal Distribution / C++ gnu

Tags: c++, random, gnu

I want to generate random points (x,y) using **log normal** distribution in c++ gnu

I know it needs parameters *mean* and *variance*, but how I can call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new cool `C++11` STL random system.

```
std::mt19937 mt(/*seed*/);
std::lognormal_distribution<float> dist(/*mean*/, /*variance*/);

float randomValue = dist(mt);
```

Comment: Its gave me error, I am using ubuntu 11.04, may it is c++ version is old!

Comment: If you use `g++` you need to add `-std=c++11`

Comment: To compile a file with `g++` with `c++11` support you do, if your file is named `main.cpp`, `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp`.
If you use Code::Blocks as an IDE, there should be an option for that in the project-preferences at the `compiler options` tab.